# BLE(BlueTooth Enable device) ios

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

How to read and write value if there are multiple properties in characteristic?

For example LED color as RGB:

> **Characteristic:** LED Color UUID: 7A5A0011-D04B-48EB-B3FA-32EB4F0FFAC4
>       LED color and intensity in RGB format. Name Green Name Blue Format
>       unsigned 8-bit integer Access read, write Value 0 - 255 Format
>       unsigned 8-bit integer Access read, write Value 0 - 255 Name Red
>       Format unsigned 8-bit integer Access read, write Value 0 - 255

So how to read/write value for RGB? Using code below I get only one value

```
if ([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:LED_Service_UUID]]){
        for (CBCharacteristic *aChar in service.characteristics) {
            /********* Characteristic: LED Link***************/

            NSLog(@"%@",aChar.UUID);

            if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: LED_CHAR_COLOR_UUID]]) {
                [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
                NSLog(@"%@%@%@",aChar.value,aChar.value,aChar.value);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([aChar.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: LED_CHAR_COLOR_UUID]]) 
{
    _colorCharacteristic = aChar; //It's a property, save it
   [peripheral readValueForCharacteristic:aChar];
}
```

This should trigger the delegate method: `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:`.

Inside, it:

```
if ([characteristic UUID] isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString: LED_CHAR_COLOR_UUID]])
{
    NSData *valueData = [characteristic value];
}
```

For each components (red, green, blue, intensity):

```
int aComponent;
NSData *aComponentData = [valueData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]; //Range to be defined for each components
[aComponentData getBytes:&aComponent length:sizeof(aComponent)];
NSLog(@"aComponent: %d", aComponent);
```

You could then create a `UIColor` from each of the components using `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`.

To write, you have to have again a `NSData` that looks respects the format used.

```
uint8_t colorValues [] = {redValue, greenValue, blueValue, intensityValue};
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:colorValues length:sizeof(colorValues)];
[_peripheral writeValue:yourValueData forCharacteristic:_colorCharacteristic type: CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];` //(or  `CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse` depending on the doc of your device).
```